# What is the best way to compare dataset from 2 different tables?

Tags: etl

What is the best way to compare dataset from 2 different tables. Here the tables contain enormous data. Also need to find out the difference in between these .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have 2 tables having same schema and little data change in SAP BODS.Now I want to write one script in python or any other language which will use SAP BODS webservices and compare these two tables and store result in output file which will be in csv format.

Answer (score 0):

you could using the except function in linq

```
var differences =
        dataTable1.AsEnumerable().Except(dataTable2.AsEnumerable(),
                                            DataRowComparer.Default);
```